# Null pointer Exception in asynctask

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask, null-pointer

Please help me why i'm getting this error.
I'm getting Json response converting into string using `convertStreamToString` method getting correct string, I can able to see this string in my logcat.
Now i'm trying to insert my json response string to sqlite database, for that i'm using

```
JSONObject HabitatObject = MyHabitatJsonObject.getJSONObject("HabitatDetails");    
JSONObject HabitatPosts = HabitatObject.getJSONObject("habitat");
    JSONArray HabitatPostsArray = HabitatPosts.getJSONArray("Post");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         DatabaseHelper InsertHabitat;     
        for (int i = 0; i < HabitatPostsArray.length(); i++) {
         values.put(InsertHabitat.PostUserImage, HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userimage").toString());
         values.put(InsertHabitat.PostUserName, HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username").toString());
    dbHabitat.insert(InsertHabitat.HABITATTABLE, null, values);
                }
```

Till now every thing is fine but when i'm trying to insert these values into database i'm getting error on this line 
`values.put(InsertHabitat.PostUserImage, HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userpostimage").toString());`

Error Log:

```
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.UserLogin.Habitat$HabitatResults.doInBackground(Habitat.java:90)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.UserLogin.Habitat$HabitatResults.doInBackground(Habitat.java:1)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-10 10:57:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is null

```
HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userpostimage")
```

Have you tried to print that value? Check the values before that line, basic checks like:

```
JSONObject jo = HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i);

if (jo == null)
    Log.d("tag", "json obj null "+i);
if (!jo.has("userpostimage"))
    Log.d("tag", "key not present, you are not parsing correctly the json");

String s = jo.getString("userpostimage");
if (s == null)
    Log.d("tag", "userpostimage null");
```

Comment: yes.. it is printing the value  in log.. this value is not coming null

Comment: You can have a null pointer on that line in 2 cases: the json object is null or there is no value for the key "userpostimage"...

Comment: they how do i overcome please help.  i can able to see json response string in log. and able to print values of json array.  this is my json reseponse string {"HabitatDetails": {"action": "success", "habitat": { "Post":[{"userpostimage": "http://www.website.com/images/1104951994.jpg",   "userid": "50","username": "Mike","info": "http://www.samplelink.com","date": "Dec 08,2011","comments": "0"},{"userpostimage": "http://www.website.com/images/164003794.jpg",   "userid": "193","username": "ajith","info": "This is sample text info","date": "Dec 07,2011","comments": "0"}]}}}

Comment: @user1090892 - try to check all the values before that line. I have added stuff to my answer above...hope it will help

Comment: the above conditions are getting failed jo is not null, jo has userpostimage and s is not null... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try Logging your JsonObject [jo], are you getting values there?
    JSONObject jo = HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i);

```
if (jo == null)
    Log.d("tag", "json obj null "+i);
else 
    Log.d("tag", "json object at index" + i + " is : " + jo.toString());
```

Comment: yes it is printing the values there.. all values of jsonobject is coming on this piece of code  values.put(InsertHabitat.PostUserImage, HabitatPostsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userimage").toString());  here PostUserImage is string type and we are converting into json result to string. values of json results is printing but in this line getting error.. Values are contentvalues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply shraddha.. got solution

Comment: Great ! Any time friend. What was the problem? Please post the solution so that it can help others too.